# Aumentar número de pool de conexões do Tomcat

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, tomcat8

estou com um problema em meu servidor de produção, aonde meu `tomcat` tem travado quando uma conexão é solicitada ao pool de conexões do banco.
Quando eu subo o `tomcat` eu vejo no `log` a seguinte mensagem :

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: Name = GaiaDataBase Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "40" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
```

Meu context.xml Está assim configurado:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxActive="40" name="jdbc/GaiaDataBase" password="blablabla" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.78/MeuBanco" username="user_desenv"/>
```

Eu pensei que `maxActive="40"` significaria que eu teria 40 conexões simultâneas no `pool`. Porém não é o que ocorre segundo o `log`.

Como aumentar então essas conexões?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O log diz que maxActive não é utilizado e que tu deveria usar em seu context.xml a tag maxTotal que por padrão é 8.
Se for este o caso deverá utilizar a flag maxTotal em vez de maxActive.

Tem que verificar o real motivo do tomcat estar "travando", ele apresenta erro 500?

Verifica se nos logs existe o erro:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients
>   already.

Caso encontre este erro tu deverá configurar de acordo com sua necessidade o arquivo de configuração do Postgres chamado postgresql.conf, dentro dele terá a flag `max_connections = 100`

Comment: Não há nada no console. 
Como eu utilizo o pool de conexões do tomcat, eu vi que ele trava na linha de comando em que o DataSource do tomcat libera uma nova conexão para o meu código.